# App crashes when selecting large amount of data from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on an app that saves data locally in SQLite DB and then syncs to the server on click of a button. The issue that I'm facing is that my app crashes when I'm trying to select data from a table which has over 1000 rows. This is how I'm selecting data:

```
Cursor crsOutletData = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE some_column_1='complete' AND some_column_2 IS NULL", null);
```

Note that some_column_1 and some_column_2 are not primary keys.

Thanks.

Comment: please add crash information from logcat when app gets crash

Comment: Usually 1000 rows is not *a large amount of data*.

Comment: what is the crash report say?

Comment: show logcat please.

Comment: I vaguely recall hearing that the Android sqlite bindings have a limit on how much data a single query can return because it tries to fetch all results into memory at once instead of lazily stepping through a row at a time. If true, might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are limitations with a Cursor, millions of rows can be handled.

The limitation is if a row contains more data than can be held in a CursorWindow (1M (earlier versions) or 2M). Typically this only happens with very large items such as images or videos.

### Example with 3,000,000 rows

Here's an example App that inserts and extracts 3 million rows are handled (albiet quite time consuming).

### 1. DBDone.java

An interface for establishing when non UI threads have completed

- (not running off the main UI thread could otherwise result in a crash due to Application Not Rrespnding (ANR))

  - 1000 rows is unlikely to result in an ANR

:-

```
public interface DBDone {
    void dbDone();
}
```

### 2. DBHelper.java

A Database helper with some basic methods to allow data to be added and retrieved (not also allows WAL or Journal mode to be selected, the latter used as that, until Android 9, is the default mode).

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TBL_TABLENAME = "table_name";
    public static final String COL_SOMECOLUMN1 = "some_column_1";
    public static final String COL_SOMECOLUMN2 = "some_column_2";

    public static final String crt_tablename_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_TABLENAME + "(" +
            COL_SOMECOLUMN1 + " TEXT, " +
            COL_SOMECOLUMN2 + " TEXT" +
            ")";

    private static boolean mWALMode = false;
    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context, boolean wal_mode) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mWALMode = wal_mode;
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onConfigure(db);
        if (mWALMode) {
            db.enableWriteAheadLogging();
        } else {
            db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(crt_tablename_sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long insert(String c1_value, String c2_value) {

        String nullcolumnhack = null;
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        if ((c1_value == null && c2_value == null)) {
            nullcolumnhack = COL_SOMECOLUMN1;
        }
        if (c1_value != null) {
            cv.put(COL_SOMECOLUMN1,c1_value);
        }
        if (c2_value != null) {
            cv.put(COL_SOMECOLUMN2,c2_value);
        }
        return mDB.insert(TBL_TABLENAME,nullcolumnhack,cv);
    }

    public long insertJustColumn1(String c1_value) {
        return this.insert(c1_value, null);
    }

    public long insertJustColumn2(String c2_value) {
        return this.insert(null,c2_value);
    }

    public Cursor getAllFromTableName() {
        return this.getAll(TBL_TABLENAME);
    }

    public Cursor getAll(String table) {
        return mDB.query(table,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

### 3. MainActivity.java

1. The MainActivity instantiates the DatabaseHelper (mDBHlpr noting that this will create the database and the underlying tables as the constructor forces the creation by getting calling **getWritableDatabase**).
2. It then calls the dbDone method which as mStage is set to 0 will empty the table in a new thread.
3. When the table has been emptied dbDone is invoked mStage will be 1 so data is added (if none exists, which it shouldn't as the table has been emptied).

   - Note adding 3,000,000 rows can take a while.
4. When the data has been inserted dbDone is invoked and as mStage is now 2 some information will be logged after extracting a Cursor will all rows. All rows in the Cursor are traversed and a count of the rows that have both columns as null are counted.

   - The number of rows extracted (3,000,000) will be written to the log.
   - The number of rows that have both columns as null will be counted (just to do something with the cursor). The number would vary as nulls are inserted randomly.

:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DBDone {

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    int mStage = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this,false);
        dbDone();
    }

    // Add some data but not in the UI Thread
    private void addData() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                addSomeData(3000000);
                dbDone(); // All done so notify Main Thread
            }
        }
        ).start();
    }

    public void dbDone() {
        switch (mStage) {
            case 0:
                emptyTable();
                break;
            case 1:
                addData();
                break;
            case 2:
                logSomeInfo();
                break;
        }
        mStage++;
    }

    /**
     * Add some rows (if none exist) with random data
     * @param rows_to_add   number of rows to add
     */
    private void addSomeData(int rows_to_add) {
        Log.d("ADDSOMEDATA","The addSomeData method hass been invoked (will run in a non UI thread)");
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase();
        if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,DBHelper.TBL_TABLENAME) > 0) return;
        // Random data that can be added to the first column
        String[] potential_data1 = new String[]{null,"complete","started","stage1","stage2","stage3","stage4","stage5"};
        // Random data that can be added to the second column
        String[] potential_data2 = new String[]{null,"something else","another","different","unusual","normal"};
        Random r = new Random();
        db.beginTransaction();
        for (int i=0; i < rows_to_add; i++) {
            mDBHlpr.insert(
                    potential_data1[(r.nextInt(potential_data1.length))],
                    potential_data2[(r.nextInt(potential_data2.length))]
            );
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
    }


    /**
     * Log some basic info from the Cursor always traversinf the entire cursor
     */
    private void logSomeInfo() {
        Log.d("LOGSOMEINFO","The logSomeInfo method has been invoked.");
        Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.getAllFromTableName();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Rows in Cursor = " + String.valueOf(csr.getCount()));
        int both_null_column_count = 0;
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            if (csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_SOMECOLUMN1)) == null && csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_SOMECOLUMN2)) == null) {
                both_null_column_count++;
            }
        }
        sb.append("\n\t Number of rows where both columns are null is ").append(String.valueOf(both_null_column_count));
        Log.d("LOGSOMEINFO",sb.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Empty the table
     */
    private void emptyTable() {
        Log.d("EMPTYTABLE","The emptyTable method has been invoked (will run in a non UI thread)");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase().delete(DBHelper.TBL_TABLENAME,null,null);
                dbDone();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

The log may well include CursorWindow full messages BUT these are handled (as the offending row will be included in the next CursorWindow) e.g. :-

```
2018-12-30 10:19:10.862 2799-2817/so53958115.so53958115 W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 404 bytes, free space 204 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
2018-12-30 10:19:11.856 2799-2817/so53958115.so53958115 W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 24 bytes, free space 11 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
2018-12-30 10:19:12.377 2799-2817/so53958115.so53958115 W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 7 bytes, free space 4 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
2018-12-30 10:19:12.902 2799-2817/so53958115.so53958115 W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 8 bytes, free space 1 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
2018-12-30 10:19:13.433 2799-2817/so53958115.so53958115 W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 24 bytes, free space 1 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
2018-12-30 10:19:13.971 2799-2817/so53958115.so53958115 W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 24 bytes, free space 21 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
2018-12-30 10:19:14.505 2799-2817/so53958115.so53958115 W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 24 bytes, free space 18 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
2018-12-30 10:19:15.045 2799-2817/so53958115.so53958115 W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 404 bytes, free space 187 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
2018-12-30 10:19:15.598 2799-2817/so53958115.so53958115 W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 7 bytes, free space 0 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
...........
```

#### Timings :-

The log includes :-

```
2018-12-30 10:17:04.610 2799-2799/? D/EMPTYTABLE: The emptyTable method has been invoked (will run in a non UI thread)
2018-12-30 10:17:04.615 2799-2817/? D/ADDSOMEDATA: The addSomeData method hass been invoked (will run in a non UI thread)
2018-12-30 10:19:10.506 2799-2817/so53958115.so53958115 D/LOGSOMEINFO: The logSomeInfo method has been invoked.
2018-12-30 10:20:17.803 2799-2817/so53958115.so53958115 D/LOGSOMEINFO: Rows in Cursor = 3000000
         Number of rows where both columns are null is 62604
```

So it took:-
- 5 ms to empty the (already empty) table.
- 2 minutes and 6 seconds to add the 3,000,000 rows.
- 1 minute and 7.5 seconds to extract and traverse the Cursor (not that you'd typically extract so many rows)

But most importantly the Cursor has coped with 3,000,000 rows. You can also see that the CursorWindow is in this case 2M (2097152 bytes).

## Conclusion

The issue is unlikely to be that 1000 rows is too large for the Cursor, although it may be, that some rows, if storing images/videos/long texts, max exceed the size that can be handled by the Cursor.

The issue is more likely due to other causes which could only be ascertained via the stack-trace in the log.

As such it's impossible to supply a specific answer without the stack-trace or more comprehensive information.

- You may find [Debug your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/) helpful.